# construct blobkey from serving url

Tags: java, google-app-engine, blobstore

Given a `BlobKey`, I know how to get the serving URL.

```
ServingUrlOptions options = ServingUrlOptions.Builder
    .withBlobKey(blobKey)
    .secureUrl(false);
String servingUrl = ImagesServiceFactory.getImagesService()
    .getServingUrl(options);
```

Is there a way to construct a BlobKey if I am given the `servingUrl`? So basically the reverse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

Detailed answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13659115/1675568) by a guy working on the App Engine PHP runtime.